# .htaccess prevent access except one directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site whose .htaccess file prevents incoming traffic except certain IP's, but now I need that the image directory can be accessed from any IP.

Here is the .htaccess file placed in the root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 87.221.15.139
allow from 127.0.0.1

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The directory allowed to be accessed from any IP is /wp-content/uploads/

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `.htaccess` file inside of `/wp-content/uploads` with the following.

```
Allow from all
```