# .htaccess Disable directory access across site EXCEPT for one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions

In my site's root directory I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
# Block access to directories without a default document.
#
# You should leave the following uncommented, as you shouldn't allow
# anyone to surf through every directory on your server (which may
# includes rather private places such as the CMS's directories).

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

And in my root I have `myFolder/` which I need to be accessible without an index.html. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664429/1757149) says to add the following .htaccess file in `myFolder/` but it doesn't seem to work, I still get error 403 forbidden:

```
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
```

So how can I block access to every directory on my site except for `myFolder/`?

**UPDATE**

In my root .htaccess I also have some rewrite rules, and the following portion is causing `myFolder/` to throw a 403 error inexplicably is the `(7) Remove ".html" from the end of urls.` section:

```
    # (7)
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\.html\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ https://mywebsitenameredacted.com/$1 [R=302]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/]+)$ /$1.html [L] # THIS LINE SPECIFICALLY
```

The last line (`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/]+)$ /$1.html [L]`) is specifically causing the page to throw a 403. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out what about this regex pattern would result in a **403 forbidden** error -- if anything it should be transforming the `myDirectory/` endpoint to something else causing a 404 error... does anyone have any ideas how this line could be causing a 403 on a directory page?

Comment: Does it work if you comment `Options -Indexes` in site root .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava Good idea, no it still doesn't work (tried multi browsers). I guess that means it's something else in my root .htaccess file? I'll have to do a deep dive before posting the whole file here because it's a huge boilerplate thing that might have some sensitive info.

Comment: May be there is something in Apache config. To test it just rename site root .htaccess to something else and see if 403 goes away or not

Comment: Yeah I removed the root .htaccess file altogether and `myFolder/` is accessible now. Something else in it is the culprit.